# End Qthread Running Custom Function (Python, PyQt4)

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4, qthread, terminate

I am trying to implement threading in a GUI I am creating. Essentially, I have a button inside the GUI that when pressed launches automation for another program. Right now I have the button launching the automation function in a separate thread. However, I can not find a way to abort the thread in the middle of the automation function. If I close the program being automated the automation function still runs in the background on an active thread and I cannot relaunch the automation function another new thread. I've tried mapping .quit() and .exit() methods to a button in the main GUI but it hasn't worked. Does anyone have any input?

Here is my thread class:

```
class WorkingThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, selector):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.selector = selector  # Selects function to run

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        if self.selector == 1:
            asa.mkdirsda(hdg_da_path, da_batch_folder, da_batch_subfolders)
        elif self.selector == 2:
            asa.mvlims(needs_gs_lims_file, subfolder_autoscore, lims_samplesheet)
        elif self.selector == 3:  # Automation function giving me trouble
            asa.gsprocess(subfolder_genomestudio, da_batch_name, lims_samplesheet_file)
        elif self.selector == 4:
            asa.mvfinalreport(subfolder_genomestudio, finalreport_file, subfolder_autoscore)
        elif self.selector == 5:
            asa.pipelineas(userid, userpass, da_batch_name, raw_data_path)
        elif self.selector == 6:
            asa.batchactv()
        return
```

This is how I am calling a new thread:

```
    self.thread_gs = WorkingThread(3)
    self.run_gs.connect(self.run_gs, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), 
                        lambda: self.thread_gs.start())
```

This is what I'm trying to map to a main GUI button to end a thread:

```
def endWorkingThread(self):
        self.thread_gs.quit()
```

Comment: Update. I found that using the .terminate() method works for me but I know this is highly discouraged. Can anyone think of a better solution?

Comment: Terminating the thread is not the problem. You need to find a way to safely terminate *the selected function* (which presumably blocks). This will allow the `run()` method to return, which will in turn end the execution of the thread.